# Partition shrink with diskpart does nothing

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning

I ran a disk shrink command in DISKPART, to shrink the C: volume 100 GB.

It took over 13 hours, and when I came back, nothing had happened. The volume size was exactly the same, but the operation had completed. There is no new unallocated space.

Here is a screenshot of Disk Management after the command completed. Notice the odd size differences between the graph at the bottom and the list at the top.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you boot Windows or Linux? Please post a screenshot from _Disk Management_, _GParted_ or similar tool. (use the [edit] button)

Comment: I am currently in Windows. The command was run from windows to start an arch dual boot. One second

Comment: Are you doing this "online", ie. shrinking the partition you've booted from? That wouldn't work. I'm not sure what happened, but you may have consolidated most data at the beginning of the partition. Some files and filesystem structures are unmovable online, though.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’m doing. Do I have to do a separate boot? Like I said, it said the operation was a success but nothing happened.

Comment: @TCoder - The built-in partition manager has some an extensive list of things it cannot do.  If you are attempting to shrink a system partition, you have to make sure data fragmentation isn't an issue, and specifically disable files that cannot be moved (i.e. page files, hibernation files, etc.).  It shouldn't take 13 hours to shrink a 1 TB partition.  I am going to guess an error occurred and that is the actual reason nothing happened.  I see nothing "odd" about any of those partition sizes.  All those partitions are perfectly normal.

Comment: No, look in the chart where is says that the size of the C: volume is 921 gb. Now, look in the list. It says 824. I am 99% sure I destroyed my partition table. I have a partition with a size of 900 GB on a volume with 800.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your backups are up to date. You're dealing with partitions, data loss can occur.

Live-boot some Linux distro with GParted from USB. I like Ubuntu and Pop!_OS for their user-friendliness, GRML is also nice albeit more advanced.

If you see a warning sign next to any partition in GParted, right-click it and choose *Check*. It will try to fix any inconsistencies, including filesystem size not matching partition size.

Then resize partitions as desired using GParted. Its NTFS support is solid and it's operating offline, which means it can move all structures that would be frozen in place when you're booting from the partition you want to operate on.

Comment: Will try this once chkdsk finishes. Thank you!